# Получить значение переменной из другого процесса через Python

Tags: python, процесс, ctypes

Есть задача - получать значения некоторых переменных из игры Dota 2 в Python, конкретно это данные выбора героев союзниками и врагами, на скрине - верхняя полоса с иконками героев. При выборе игроком персонажа, пустое окно над никнеймом заменяется на иконку выбранного героя. Этот выбор мне и нужно отследить через процесс. Далее, по набору id героев уже готовый алгоритм подскажет, какой персонаж выгоднее всего смотрится в этом драфте (наборе героев союзников и врагов).

[image: ...]

Осуществимы ли такие операции с процессами через Python? Если, например я выделил набор адресов к этим переменным и просто хочу получать данные, то как это реализовать? Адреса динамические, поэтому к ним нужно прибавлять значение сдвига насколько я понимаю, а я мало что понимаю в этих сдвигах, адресах. Пользуюсь Cheat Engine для просмотра памяти, Python 3.6 на Windows.

Answer (score 1):

если уже есть адрес, то можно извлечь информацию с помощью [ctypes.string_at](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.string_at)

```
from ctypes
a = 0x7fff 
print ctypes.cast(id(a), ctypes.py_object).value
```

Но проблема может быть с типом объекта. Хорошо, если это примитивный тип, но что, если это другой, более сложный?

В Python-е можно подключить С++ и выполнить код для получения данных с памяти. Например,

```
#include <cstdint>

uintptr_t p = 0x0001FBDC;
int value = *reinterpret_cast<int *>(p);
```

подробнее [тут](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html)

**UPDATE**

Действительно, память делится на 2 части: для системы и для юзера. 
И современные ОС выделяют виртуальную память под каждый процесс для изоляции.

Но кто сказал, что нельзя все таки получить память другого процесса.

```
LCPVOID Address = (LPCVOID)Ox012d5678;

// тут будем считывать данные из другого процесса.
char buffer[64]; 
DWORD ProcessId = // ID нужного нам процесса
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, 0, ProcessId); // открываем хэндл нужного процесса

ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, Address, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0); //считываем данные по адресу из другого процесса
cout << buffer << endl;
```

Comment: Так ваш адрес завязан на ваше виртуальное адресное пространство. Если можно было так просто получать доступ к памяти другого процесса, то сколько бы вирусов у нас было? :)
По топику. Вам тут стоит посмотреть в сторону межпроцессного взаимодействия.

Comment: тип значений - int, это id героев, это, я так понимаю примитивный тип?)

Comment: спасибо, оказывается всё намного сложнее чем я думал), необходимо знать си...

Comment: @Frank Ну-у-у, если почитать вот это: https://habr.com/ru/post/346258/?utm_campaign=346258 то не обязательно "лезть в память". Для неискушённого читателя всё выглядит довольно просто - как 2 байта переслать.